# How can i get a single object?

Tags: python, django

Model:

```
class Contacts(models.Model):
  libId = models.ForeignKey(verbose_name='Библиотека', to=Libraries, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  name = models.CharField('ФИО', max_length=257, blank=True)
  position = models.CharField('Должность/название отдела', max_length=257)
  phoneNum = models.BigIntegerField('Номер телефона', validators=[MaxValueValidator(79999999999)])

  def __str__(self):
      return self.name
```

Serializer:

```
class ContactsSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Contacts
    fields = '__all__'
```

I can get all objects from that model:

```
class ContactsView(generics.ListAPIView):
  serializer_class = ContactsSerializers
  queryset = Contacts.objects.all()
```

But how can i get one from user input?

Comment: You should work with a `RetrieveAPIView` instead of a `ListView`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `RetriveAPIView` to get single object like this:

```
class ContactsView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
  serializer_class = ContactsSerializers
  queryset = Contacts.objects.all()
  lookup_field = 'pk'
```

Your url should be look like this:

```
path('some-path-goes/<int:pk>/', ContactsView.as_view(), name='some_name')
```